# What does "morning wet" refer to?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I recently read the story "The Sign of the Four", by Arthur Conan Doyle. In it, one particular phrase stood out:

> ...rubbing their sleeves across their beards after their morning wet.

I believe it refers to them taking a drink or something. Could it refer to a morning dip perhaps?

Also, where does this phrase originate from? When was it first used,etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As jwpat7 explained quite well, it refers to a drink of alcohol.

The OED's earliest reference for *wet* as a noun with the meaning

> A drink or draught of some alcoholic beverage; a glass of liquor.

is listed as:

> 1719   in T. D'Urfey Wit & Mirth V. 125   *At Noon he gets up for a wet and to Dine.*

I'd imagine it is derived from the expression *to wet one's whistle*, meaning *to drink*, which appears as early as the 14th century:

> c1386   Chaucer Reeve's Tale 235   *So was hir ioly whistle wel y-wet.*

Answer (score 7):

Slightly [more context](http://classiclit.about.com/library/bl-etexts/acdoyle/bl-acdoyle-sign-7.htm) makes the meaning clear:

> At the square-topped corner public-houses business was just beginning, and rough-looking men were emerging, rubbing their sleeves across their beards after their morning wet.

A *[public-house](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/public-house)*, or *[public house](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/public_house#English)*, is "an establishment licensed to sell alcoholic beverages", that is, a tavern, bar, saloon or *[local](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/local#Noun)* ("One's nearest or regularly frequented public house or bar").  That is, the sentence refers to men coming out of a bar after having a pint or two of beer, ale, stout, etc.

I have no information about the origin of the phrase or its first use.